# How to do multiple user logins with different inputs in jMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have multiple login ids. I want to simulate a user Login.
I first tried picking a first row login details and also tried it by those in a loop controller, but its not picking row by row.

How to assign for each user to pick every row, through threads with multi login.

Answer (score 9):

Yes i have done this simply in three steps as,

1.Create a text file (or csv file) containing the user names and passwords, separated by commas. Put this in the same directory as your test plan as,

[image]

2.Add a CSV DataSet configuration element to the test plan. Name the variables USER and PASS. also,Add a path to the filename in that element (I made sure to check the file path) as,

[image]

3.Replace the login name with ${USER} and the password with ${PASS} on the Log in (HTTP Request) Sampler as,
[image]

Hope this will help you,

Comment: any problem feel free to ask.

Comment: If using '.txt' file, avoid adding any space between the username and the password. Adding space between user/pass added '%20' in the JMeter request.

Answer (score 0):

The video tutorial for [Login Authentication in JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/80479-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication) was helpful for me. If you want to use different usernames and passwords, you can use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)