# .csv file is not read by Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, load, performance-testing, load-testing

I have CSV DataSet Config where I have location of my .csv file

Tried both by writing the absolute path and putting my file in the same directory. Below is the screenshot
[CSV file gets stored but the next line says it must exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc3vv.png)

Below is mine HTTP Request
[HTTP REquest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtPg4.png)

By running this in command Line nothing is getting stored in the my output file
I have tried that too.

Comment: Type "E:\InputData.csv" in Run Command and see if your file opens.
if Not Type "E:\InputData.csv.txt" in Run Command, you might have .txt extension hidden in your folder option.

Also try adding "UTF-8" in File encoding option of CSV DataSet Config.

Answer (score 0):

Check following things:

Name of the file is correct. In case of Unix file names are case sensitive so check the name of the file and name you have mentioned in CSV data set configuration.

Keep the CSV file in the same folder where your JMX resides, and just mention file name in CSV dataset config. This avoids confusion in future even if you move the script to any other box.

Also make sure in the file there is no new line character at the end of the file. That will result in error.

Comment: I have tried all those things But still didn't get me anywhere

Comment: done this, Keep the CSV file in the same folder where your JMX resides, and just mention file name in CSV dataset config. This avoids confusion in future even if you move the script to any other box.

Comment: Yup Done all those and its with the screenshot as well 

Stil not able to fetch the .csv file and more I check the .jmx file There is no issue in that too

Comment: save csv file & close it. then run the test.

Comment: I can open my CSV file both by excel and notepad
Is that causing the issue

Comment: Use notepad i.e. .txt file for avoiding such issue. my this answer will be helpful for this as, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389131/how-to-do-multiple-user-logins-with-different-inputs-in-jmeter/19396973#19396973

Answer (score -1):

Try a fully qualified path. ~/... was not working for me either - /temp/file.csv did the trick

Comment: Please read the question again: the OP used a fully qualified path.